# How to arrange the output from Perl :: Mechanize in a concise order (with variables or names)

Tags: perl, parsing, store, www-mechanize

I run linux opensuse 11.4.  I try to run this little programme on a linux box.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

    use WWW::Mechanize::Firefox;
    my $mech = WWW::Mechanize::Firefox->new();

    open(INPUT, "urls.txt") or die "Can't open file: $!";

    while (<INPUT>) {
      chomp;
      $mech->get($_);
      my $png = $mech->content_as_png();
    }
    close(INPUT);
    exit;
```

I have a list of URLS - more than 1000 URLS - so it might be a problem if I get the results in an unsorted way.

I have a list of 1000 URLs, one on each line, saved in a file. I want the script above to open the file, read a line, then retrieve the website! The URLS are stored something like this:

```
    Filename: urls.txt
    ------------------
    www.google.com
    www.cnn.com
    www.msnbc.com
    news.bbc.co.uk
    www.bing.com
    www.yahoo.com
```

How can I write the script so that the thumbnail-images are stored with certain names - e.g., with the domain names. Otherwise the results would be a whole mess. I need to identify the thumbnails based on the URLS. Is this possible?

Comment: What's with the references to 'PHP Code'?

Comment: hi - just cleaned it up a bit!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
open my $out, '>', "$_.png" or die "could not open '$_.png' for output $!";
print $out $png;
close $out;
```

Comment: hi there - many many thanks for the reply. GREAT to hear from you -greetings